# Android ImageView is not displayed

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I ran into an issue concerning two `ImageViews` which are displayed on the layout.xml but not when running the app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Outter Linear Layout  -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearOutter"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#e6e6e9" >

<!-- First inner Linear Layout -->
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearInner1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="0.18"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/moyland_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/moyland" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hsrw_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/hsrw" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Title -->

<org.hsrw.artandcycle.util.AutoResizeTextView
    android:id="@+id/widget37"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/app_name_upper"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#0C1273"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textSize="100sp" />

<!-- Second inner Linear Layout -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearInner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.18"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gelderland_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/erfgoed_gelderland" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/interreg_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/interreg" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Third inner Linear Layout -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearInner3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.18"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/erw_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/erw" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gelderland2_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/province_gelderland" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/foerder_logo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.18"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/foerder" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wfg_logo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.18"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/wfg" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my layout. Everything is displayed as it is supposed to be but the last two image views are not displayed on my Galaxy Nexus.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that there is enough space on your screen to present all Images? Since your root view is LinearLayout with vertical orientation, it can be that your last "row" of ImageViews is out of screen.

Also, I am not sure what are you doing there, but maybe problem is in android:layout_height="0dp".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The height is set to 0dp because the weight takes care of the scale. Just like the images above. The sum of all all weights is 1 concerning the outter linear layout.

Comment: Even if I use just one ImageView after the TextView which is weighted 0.7, the image of this view is not shown as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the dimension of the last two images.

I reduced the width of those images to 800. Before the width was about 1300 pixels.